# Dynamic pivot SQL query with bcp gives "Unable to resolve column level collations. BCP copy out failed" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot, bcp

I am trying to use dynamic sql to pivot one column ("Question") into several columns (Question text) in a table with 7 columns. The corresponding data to the one column I want to pivot is in a single column ("Answer"), but the columns in the pivoted table will be under the new columns (Question text) . I am using bcp to copy the query output to a file, and am getting the error "Unable to resolve column-level collations. Copy out failed." What can I do to address this?

I am using Microsoft Sql Server 17 and bcp through Powershell in SQL Server Agent Jobs. I have already tried using dynamic sql to simply select columns, rather than pivoting the table, and I get the same error.
[image]
The above is similar to the table I'm using. I want to Pivot the Question column into 4 separate columns with the answer below the question text. the final table should have one row since the Id is the same.

This is the code that stuffs the Question column into a single column:

```
    DECLARE @cols nVARCHAR(MAX), @DynamicPivotQuery nVARCHAR(max); 
set @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTinct ','+ QUOTENAME(Question) from db.testforpivot FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 
select @cols;
```

---

gives:

[image]

This is the code for the dynamic pivot:

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 'SELECT Id,' + @cols+' ( select Id, name, user, extId, Question, score1 from db.testforpivot ) x pivot ( MAX(Answer)for Question in ('+@cols+')) as pivotResult' 
exec sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

---

when I run the following bcp command, I get the error mentioned above:

```
bcp "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
sql code above here" queryout C:\Users\ssingla\Documents\EvalExportLast24Hrs.txt -c  -t -T
```

I am expecting the following:
[image]

### etc, with scores next to answers

edit 8/3/19
Thanks to folks who have pointed me in the right direction. The following queries are working for dynamic pivot in MSSMS. The key missing points in existing explanations are that the brackets '[' and ']' resulting from QUOTENAME need to be replaced with empty strings in the dynamic pivot. I will test bcp on Monday:

```
DECLARE @cols nVARCHAR(MAX),
@DynamicPivotQuery nVARCHAR(max);
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTinct ','+ QUOTENAME(Question) from tempdb.dbo.test FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
select @cols;

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
'select *
from 
(
  select *
    from tempdb.dbo.test
) a
pivot
(
  max(Answer)
  for Question in ('+STUFF(REPLACE(REPLACE(@cols,'[', ''),']',''),1,1,'')+')
) p';
exec sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: Does your dynamic pivot produce the desired result set if you execute it in SSMS without BCP?

Comment: How do you see the result in SSMS? I get a message that says query successful. I was trying to figure out how to see the resulting table but couldn’t.

Comment: sorry, ignore my earlier comment if it doesn't show as deleted... that was confusing. What Tab is asking you to do is to execute the command you are into BCP with "queryout". What is the full command that is given to bcp queryout? Try to execute that statement in it's own SSMS query window.

Comment: Thanks folks for pointing me in the right direction.  I have the dynamic SQL with dynamic pivot working in MSSMS. I can't test compatibility with bcp until Monday, so I'll post again then. There seem to be some key things missing from current explanations of how to implement dynamic pivots.......see next comment for queries that work.

Comment: Did you have to fix anything on the dynamic pivot query? I highly doubt that BCP is having difficulty exporting the results of the query due to how the data was queried. BCP does not interpret or compile the query at all. This is passed along to SQL Server just like any other connection. By the time BCP is involved, there is just a tabular set of data to extract that is detached from how it was queried.

Comment: The good news should be, if your query is executing successfully in SSMS, then BCP should now work as well. It only works with the results.

Comment: thanks Jamie. Everything is working correctly now, with one exception. I am trying to add column names to the exported file, and a simple command like----bcp "select 'test';" queryout C:\Users\ssingla\Documents\columns.txt -c -T   gives an error Unhandled exception: System.Format Exception. Index(zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than...Not sure why, since this query works in MSSQLMS